# What to look for in HTML5 / CSS3 editors?

Tags: html

I'm about to start learning HTML5 and I'd like to pick an editor.   Currently I have Aptana3, HTML-Kit build 292, and Adobe CS Dreamweaver 4.    I'd like to avoid spending any money if I can.

Does HTML5 or CSS3 create any special requirements for choosing an editor or would any of the above be adequate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uh, any text editor will do? A more powerful one is better, obviously, but text is all it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any editor will be fine (I use eclipse/aptana). more important for developing html5/css3 will be a good browser, that supports the new standards (and can debug) -> firefox+firebug, opera or chrome. just don't develop with IE or Safari.

Comment: chrome and safari both use webkit, results on both should be the same. dunno with safari on mac though.

Comment: yep, chrome and safari use the same rendering engine, but they have different hardware access/grafics engines (to draw it to the screen). They also have different javascript engines, so the performance is very different. Chrome has V8, which is highly optimized. Safari5 has Nitro, which used to be fast, but is surpassed by IE9, Chrome, Firefox4..

Comment: Safari uses SquirrelFish Extreme as far is i know (rebranded as Nitro) which surpasses V8. but i really think it's the safari browser that's slow. wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#JavaScriptCore SFX vs V8: http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2008/09/squirrelfish-extreme-mops-floor-with-v8-tracemonkey.ars

Comment: well, thats a very outdated link :) here is an (also outdated) link from some performance analysis microsoft did; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/26/understanding-differences-in-hardware-acceleration-through-paintball.aspx

Answer (score 1):

HTML5/CSS3 should cause no significant problems for choosing an editor. The worst that can happen is a keyword is not highlighted because the editor does not recognise it. Many people will recommend you not to use an IDE for web development, but whatever you are most comfortable with is best.

Answer (score 1):

Any IDE will do actually (even notepad will do)

What you need in an IDE if you are starting to learn HTML5/CSS3:

- **Code auto-complete** so you won't be going back and forth to a website for reference
- **Code Validation** so it warns you when you are typing wrong code
- **Auto-indent** so you can see the code properly and teach you how to properly indent
- **Color-coded code** to differentiate the code you are typing
- **Extensible** so that you can just add-in additional features
- **Free** so it won't hurt your pockets to buy one and dump if you don't like

i used [Aptana Studio 3](http://aptana.com/) when i started learning. Might be fit for you too

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference goes to [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) because it's very simple to use. It has very good syntax highlighting and it offers good code completion.

If you get into scripting a bit more than [code snippets](http://web-design-weekly.com/2012/07/03/snippets-in-sublime-text-2/) will also become a very useful time-saving feature for you.